# Access Hive views from spark with spark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to access Hive views with the spark session and end up with the below exception.

**Exception:**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o67.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD'
```

However, when I explicitly use SQLcontext and it works fine. Is there any way to stick to the spark session without the use of SQLcontext?

Here is the code

> example_df = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM slide.mex_campaign_booking LIMIT 100""")

where *spark* is a spark session.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Could you please add your select statement, that throws such exception?

Comment: Looks like there is a mistake in a query so please add a code block which is not working.

Comment: Were you able to fix the error? If yes, could you please share how you fixed it?